# Serial Interface Communication and Spaces

Tags: c++, serial-port

I want to send two commands to a µC per USB. One of this commands is be succesful transmitted. The other resoltues only in a "Invalid Command"-Message from the µC.

Both Commands exists and are correctly dialed. I had proff them by using a other program and in the SourceCode of the µC.

I send the commands by this codelines:

```
if(!WriteFile(hSerial, c_command1, sizeof(c_command1), &dwBytesWrite, NULL)) 
{ 
    cerr << "Error: Reading failure" << endl; 
}
```

My first command (that who works):
    START\r\n

The second command:
    PARAM NR 5\r\n

The *\r\n* means a CR-LF which means "Command is over".

I think the communication has some problem with the space.
Can anybody help me? A hint what I should change?

-casisto

Comment: The space is very unlikely to be the problem. Show us how you set c_command1. Check that sizeof gives the length you expect. Tell us what dwBytesWrite is after the write. Use a debugger in the µC or a PC monitoring the sending line to find out what is being sent.

Comment: setting c_command: 
char c_command1[] = "PARAM NR 5\r\n";
or

Comment: setting c_command: 
char c_command1[] = "PARAM NR 5\r\n";
or
char c_command2[] = "START\r\n";

sizeOf c_command1 = 13; c_command2 = 8; seems to be right...

DWORD dwBytesWrite = 0; --> for counting the written bytes...

a monitoring programm I will try as next.

Comment: ok, I checked it with "Device Monitoring Studio", thats my results: 

    PARAM NR 5...
    START...

Answer (score 0):

Your tests seem to indicate that the COM port output is working. One possible problem is that the sizeof your command strings includes their terminating null so you are sending the terminating null along with each command. The µC may not like that.

Comment: The problem was not a sign  to much, it was a sign to less... "\r" will only be "1" sign, but it works when it is "2" signs... I have now     strlen()+2  
and its works...